# How to compare only the last element from a property set from multiple nodes in Neo4j without knowing the length of the property set?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-cql

In Neo4j I have multiple nodes with  property sets of multiple lengths.

For example, a set of nodes

```
    (id:PERSON{userid:0, education_school_id[21,25,29]})
    (id:PERSON{userid:1, education_school_id[21]})
    (id:PERSON{userid:2, education_school_id[21,25]})
    (id:PERSON{userid:3, education_school_id[21,25,27]})
    (id:PERSON{userid:4, education_school_id[21,25,66]})
    (id:PERSON{userid:5, education_school_id[21,25,27]})
    (id:PERSON{userid:6, education_school_id[21,25,29,43,22]})
    (id:PERSON{userid:7, education_school_id[21,22]})
    (id:PERSON{userid:8, education_school_id[21,25]})
    (id:PERSON{userid:9, education_school_id[21,25,27,24,32]})
    (id:PERSON{userid:10, education_school_id[21,25,66,29]})
    (id:PERSON{userid:11, education_school_id[21,25,44]})
```

Now I want a **cypher query statement** that only compares the last property of all the property sets and group the nodes according to their userid as follows

```
29    0,10
21    1
25    2,8
32    9
44    10
22    6,7
27    3,5
66    4
```

[order is not important]

This will be somewhat like comparing to `array[length-1]` for an array.

I do not know the lengths of the individual lists.

Currently I am using,

```
match(n) where  exists(n.education_school_id) return  n.education_school_id, collect(n.userid) ;
```

However, this groups the nodes by property sets as a whole.

Any help will be appreciated.

**On another note:** Lot of my questions are getting downvoted recently. If any person wants to downvote, feel free to do so, but leave some constructive criticism. I try to make my questions as close to the rules of the site as possible. Leave tips where I am going wrong in spite of all my efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [`last()`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/#functions-last) function.

---

I didn't downvote, but you've posted a number of questions where the answer in simply in the documentation, like this one. It's not a complex question, you could have found it yourself, it doesn't really feel like you're trying, which is what's expected on SO. There's the developer manual which I already linked to, there's also the Cypher reference card which has a [List Expressions section](http://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/3.0/) where everything is in condensed form.

Comment: Thank you and apologies. Truth be told, I have gone through the documentation as well as the ref card multiple times. Probably did not realize what exactly I was looking for,